# Get Raw json string in Newtonsoft.Json Library

Tags: .net, json, json.net

I have json like this

```
{
    "name": "somenameofevent",
    "type": "event",
    "data": {
        "object": {
            "age": "18",
            "petName": "18"
        },
        "desct": {
        }
    }
}
```

and I have 2 objects like this

```
public class CustEvent
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string EventType{ get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public SomeData Data{ get; set; }
}

public class SomeData
{
    [JsonProperty("object")]
    public String SomeObject { get; set;}
    [JsonProperty("dsct")]
    public String SomeDesct { get; set; }
}
```

I use to parse json to object Newtonsoft.NET library. And how i can get RAW JSON into SomeObject , SomeDesct        properties ?    In JSON "data.object ..." are complex object and i want to get only RAW JSON String to those properties. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 28):

**You don't need to write any converters,** just use the [`JRaw`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JRaw.htm) type as follows:

```
public class SomeData
{
    [JsonProperty("object")]
    public JRaw SomeObject { get; set;}
    [JsonProperty("dsct")]
    public JRaw SomeDesct { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can access the raw value by checking the `.Value` property:

```
var rawJsonDesct = (string)data.SomeDesct.Value;
```

If you want to retain the `string` signature, just serialize the JSON to a hidden property and have the string conversion in the accessor call instead.

Comment: Definitely the easiest solution.

Comment: This doesn't keep indent, any solution to that?

Comment: Important Note: `JRaw` doesn't preserve the original data. It normalizes strings, removes whitespace and truncates long decimals (losing potentially significant data).

Comment: I don't know why this option is not mentioned more. It seems like the best solution, for when you want to not parse part of an object (typically a payload that you want to keep as a string for later use).

Answer (score 9):

You have to write a custom converter class (derived from `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter`) which instructs the deserializer to read the whole object and to return the JSON string for the object.

Then you have to decorate the property with the `JsonConverter` attribute.

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(YourCustomConverterClass))]
public string SomeObject { get; set; }
```

There are good tutorials on the web on how to create custom converters, but - for your convenience - the core of your converter might look like this:

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    return JObject.Load(reader).ToString();
}
```

This method reads a complete JSON object but returns the serialized version of the object as string. There is a bit of overhead because the object is deserialized to a `JObject` and then serialized again, but for me it's the easiest way to do this. Maybe you have a better idea.

Comment: A more efficient ReadJson could use the same technique as JRaw uses internally. See implementation of ReadJson in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17601556/27846

Answer (score 4):

I use this implementation of the custom JsonConverter.

```
public class RawJsonConverter: JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(string);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        JsonToken previousToken = JsonToken.None;

        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
        {
            sb.Append('{');
            int depth = 1;
            while (depth > 0)
            {
                if (!reader.Read())
                    break;
                switch (reader.TokenType)
                {
                    case JsonToken.PropertyName:
                        if (previousToken == JsonToken.Boolean || previousToken == JsonToken.Integer || previousToken == JsonToken.Float)
                            sb.Append(',');
                        sb.AppendFormat("\"{0}\":", reader.Value);
                        break;
                    case JsonToken.StartArray:
                        if (previousToken == JsonToken.EndArray)
                            sb.Append(',');
                        sb.Append('[');
                        break;
                    case JsonToken.Boolean:
                    case JsonToken.Integer:
                    case JsonToken.Float:
                        if (previousToken == JsonToken.Boolean || previousToken == JsonToken.Integer || previousToken == JsonToken.Float)
                            sb.Append(',');
                        sb.AppendFormat(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", reader.Value);
                        break;
                    case JsonToken.EndArray:
                        sb.Append(']');
                        break;
                    case JsonToken.StartObject:
                        sb.Append('{');
                        depth++;
                        break;
                    case JsonToken.EndObject:
                        sb.Append('}');
                        depth--;
                        break;
                }
                previousToken = reader.TokenType;
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteRawValue(value.ToString());
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are worried about the overhead because the object is deserialized to a `JObject` a and then serialized again (**solution offered by @fero** ) then you can try the following.

**Approach 1**: Create your own custom `JsonConverter` and override `ReadJson`

```
using(var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(myTextReader))
{
  while(jsonReader.Read()){
    if(jsonReader.TokenType.PropertyName=="SomeDesct")
    {
      //do what you want
    } 
  }
}
```

For more detail check the link [Incremental JSON Parsing in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026508/incremental-json-parsing-in-c-sharp)

**Approach 2**: Read the json string and apply string functions or regex function to get the desired string.

Answer (score 1):

As [chakrit suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34150061/50358), you can do something like this to provide a string signature for your object, while using JRaw to do the real work.

```
    [JsonProperty("Data")]
    public JRaw Raw { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Data
    {
        get => Raw?.Value as string;
        set => Raw = new JRaw(value);
    }
```

Comment: Or the opposite `[JsonIgnore] public string Data; [JsonProperty("Data")] public JRaw DataRaw => new JRaw(Data);` works pretty well and doesn't need type conversions when using the data in other ways.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can directly use the static method from JsonConvert class

> PopulateObject(string value, object target, JsonSerializerSettings settings);