# Serialize anonymous type with literal JSON properties

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-mvc-5

How can I easily return responses that have a mix of normal objects and literal JSON strings that should be emitted inline in the JSON stream, exactly as-is without interpretation or encoding?

```
public JsonResult Something() {
   var literalJson = "{\"a\":1,\"b\":2}";
   return Json(new {
      result = "success",
      responseTime = DateTimeOffset.Now(),
      data = literalJson // only, don't JSON-encode this, emit it as-is
   });
}
```

Creating a `LiteralJson` class could work, with a custom `Converter` for it. But I'm not sure that makes the most sense.

I know how to make a custom `Converter` if that's a solid implementation. Are there any other ways to achieve the same goal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON.NET: Serialize json string property into json object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584701/json-net-serialize-json-string-property-into-json-object)

Comment: @FedericoDipuma I swear I searched for 30 minutes!

Comment: The keyword was *JSON.NET*. You need to switch to that library for the serialization however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Json.Net installed you can use a `JRaw`:

```
public ContentResult Something()
{
    var literalJson = "{\"a\":1,\"b\":2}";

    var resp = new
    {
        result = "success",
        responseTime = DateTimeOffset.Now,
        data = new Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JRaw(literalJson)
    };

    return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resp), "application/json", Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

But note that you will need to use Json.Net's serializer for this to work.  That is why I changed the above code to use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` and return a `ContentResult` rather than the using the controller's `Json` method like you had shown originally.  The `Json` method uses `JavaScriptSerializer` internally, which doesn't know how to handle a `JRaw`.

Comment: I knew there had to be another way. Why make my own `RawJson` class when a `JRaw` already exists? Thanks for the information. I do use Json.Net but was trying to stick with pure MVC just to avoid polluting possible answers—but am happy to use the Newtonsoft product in any case.