# Unable to deserialize JSON into Object using C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have been on this issue all morning and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong here.

Here is the XML I am working with.

```
{
    "item1": "{\"id\":\"53553621-da48-47dd-bad6-6e9d2b3c785f\",\"auth_token\":\"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJDT0VMS0VSQFBPVU5EU0xBQlMuQ09NIiwianRpIjoiZjBlMjI3OTYtMTY4NC00MmRlLWE0ZDYtZDhiYmVlZmRmNmQ2IiwiaWF0IjoxNTg0NTU4ODg5LCJyb2wiOiJhcGlfYWNjZXNzIiwiaWQiOiI1MzU1MzYyMS1kYTQ4LTQ3ZGQtYmFkNi02ZTlkMmIzYzc4NWYiLCJuYmYiOjE1ODQ1NTg4ODgsImV4cCI6MTU4NDU2NjA4OCwiaXNzIjoid2ViQXBpIiwiYXVkIjoiYXBpLm1pbGxtYW5tdWx0aW1lZGlhLmNvbTo0MDQwIn0.dthKzyJRqtkanYNRWEkiqYf4yzQT_A9Qn-GkH5eNAwM\",\"expires_in\":7200}",
    "item2": "105"
}
```

item1 is a standard auth token I will need to pull and pass to make API calls, I need that auth_token out of there mainly.
item2 is a custom field being returned.
For some reason it errors out whenever I try to de-serialize this JSON into my object.

```
public class AuthToken
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string auth_token { get; set; }
    public int expires_in { get; set; }
}

public class Token
{
    public AuthToken item1 { get; set; }
    public string item2 { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the code I am de-serializing with

```
var t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(token,
                        new JsonSerializerSettings
                        {
                            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
                        });
```

Error I am receiving

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Error converting value
ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to MyAppName.AuthToken.
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you try this?  JSON.NET: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584701/json-net-serialize-json-string-property-into-json-object

Comment: I'm going to be nitpicky. The action "construct an object from -usually- stored data" is called deserialization, serialize is just the opposite.

Comment: Your items are escaped strings so the deserialiser is going to think that it is simply a string value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `AuthToken` isn't a string.

Your token is stored as string literal data.

Edit the source code for make authtoken string (and then convert it to AuthToken), or make the serializer serialize AuthToken data structure.

```
public class AuthToken
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string auth_token { get; set; }
    public int expires_in { get; set; }
}

public class Token
{
    public string item1{get; set;}
    private AuthToken _token;

    public AuthToken AuthToken{ get { return _token ?? _token= new AuthToken(item1);}}
    public string item2 { get; set; }
}
```

You have to make the `AuthToken` ctor.

Or you just can create a `JsonConverter` which makes what you want.