# Receiving JSON object as a string in ASP.NET Core API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi

Is there a way for me to receive a `json` object as a string and **not** convert to a class in my Web API?

If I create a class that matches the structure of the `json` object I receive, everything works nicely because the `ModelBinder` handles it. However, if I try to keep it as a string, it's failing. The value of `transaction` parameter ends up being `null` -- see my API method below.

This is what my `CreditCardTransaction` class looks like that I use to receive data into my API method:

```
public class CreditCardTransaction
{
   public int Amount { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public string Token { get; set; } // This is the json object
}
```

And my API method looks like this:

```
[HttpPost("process")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ProcessPayment([FromBody] CreditCardTransaction transaction)
{
   if(transaction == null || !ModelState.IsValid)
      return new StatusCodeResult(400);

   // Process transaction
}
```

I'm doing this for Stripe Checkout integration where Stripe frontend client converts sensitive credit card data into what they call a token which is a `json` object. So, in my backend API, I just want to receive the token along with a couple of simple data points i.e. amount and description.

If I set my `CreditCardTransaction` class to the above structure, `transaction` ends up getting a `null` value. Looks like `ModelBinder` doesn't like the idea of having a `json` object in `Token` property which is defined as a `string`.

If I create a class that matches the structure of the `json` object for the `token`, I'm able to receive it but it's causing other issues for me, not to mention all the unnecessary conversions.

I do NOT need the `token` except to pass it to Stripe's API to complete the transaction. I will not save it or manipulate it. Looks like Stripe's API is expecting a `json` object anyway so I simply want to receive it and pass it to their API as is without messing with it.

How do I receive this `json` object?

Comment: Did you try using the dynamic keyword? You can get an idea here about the usage of dynamic keyword. There is no need to define a POCO class. http://www.carlserver.com/blog/post/using-c%23-dynamic-keyword-to-replace-data-transfer-objects

Comment: Sorry I am a bit confused... is Task<IActionResult> a standard object?  Or can you show the definition

Comment: @Baskar Yes! dynamic worked! Thank you. Please post it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Try using the dynamic keyword? You can get an idea here about the usage of dynamic keyword. There is no need to define a POCO class. http://www.carlserver.com/blog/post/using-c%23-dynamic-keyword-to-replace-data-transfer-objects

Comment: Just declare `Token` to be a `JToken` or `JRaw`.  See [Get Raw json string in Newtonsoft.Json Library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10757450/3744182).

Comment: @dbc I think this is a good approach too but it requires me to create a class that matches the structure of the `json` object. I'd rather not even mess with it. Thank you for your suggestion though.

Comment: Actually, `dynamic` is not doing the trick. I got excited because I was capturing the values but then I end up performing a lot of tricks to convert `dynamic` into a `jObject`. I really should be able to receive `string` but for some reason it's not working.

Comment: I'm back to using the `dynamic` option. Once I get the data in a `dynamic` object, I serialize it using Newtonsoft `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()`. This seems to be working but seems unnecessarily complex.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Core MVC : How to get raw JSON bound to a string without a type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31952002/asp-net-core-mvc-how-to-get-raw-json-bound-to-a-string-without-a-type)

Answer (score 6):

Just read from `Request.Body` stream:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ProcessPayment()
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
            string rawValue = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
    ...
}
```

---

Updated: the following doesn't work with ASP.NET Core 2.0.

Actually, the `string` type for parameter should work if you post with `Content-Type: application/json`:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ProcessPayment([FromBody] string transaction)
{
    ...
}
```

There is a good article about all these things:
[Accepting Raw Request Body Content in ASP.NET Core API Controllers](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/Sep/14/Accepting-Raw-Request-Body-Content-in-ASPNET-Core-API-Controllers)

Comment: The `Content-Type` is already set to `application/json` but for some reason, if I try to receive `string`, it's not working. I end up getting a `null` value in `transaction` parameter.

Comment: @Sam yeh, looks like the second option doesn't work with ASP.NET Core 2.0... Thought reading directly from `Request.Body` is working

Comment: I had to go back to the `dynamic` option. I then serialize the object using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()`. Seems so unnecessary!

Comment: unncessary is the name of the game when it comes to .net core. Takes a week to just get to where express init starts you off.