# Out of memory for JObject

Tags: c#, json, parsing, json.net

I have a problem when I try to parse a large `json` file, which has around `200mb`.
I'm doing it with `Newtonsoft.Json`. It gives `OutOfMemory` exception.

This is my code:

```
using (StreamReader sr=File.OpenText("path"))
        {
            JObject file= (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(new JsonTextReader(sr));
        }
```

How can I do this ? ( preferable using JObject )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `JsonTextReader` to read text in a `DataReader` fashion as stated in this question:

[Incremental JSON Parsing in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026508/incremental-json-parsing-in-c-sharp)

You will have to code your own logic to process JSON data, but it will for sure solve your memory issues:

```
using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(File.OpenText("path")))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // Your logic here (anything you need is in [reader] object), for instance:
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
        {
            // Process array
            MyMethodToProcessArray(reader);
        }
        else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
        {
            // Process object
            MyMethodToProcessObject(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

You would actually build a recursive JSON parser.

Comment: it seems var property=jsonReader.TokenType.PropertyName; doesn't work. It says 'PropertyName cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead'

Comment: I updated the answer adding some sample code.  Using JsonTextReader is like creating a parser from scratch (quite an amount of work if your JSON structure is complex) but, if you feel comfortable with that, it will allow you to avoid your memory issues.

Comment: Thank you. But how can I acces fields from that file ? For smaller json files I would have done it like this: I would have created an JObject and iterate through it and I could have accessed elements like this item["field_name"].Value<string>().  How can I do that with reader?

Comment: When `reader.TokenType` is `JsonToken.PropertyName`, that means that you just read the name of the JSON field (or property).  You can access the name of the property in `reader.Value`.  Next call to `reader.Read()` will read the value of that property, which will be placed in `reader.Value` as well.  It's easy but, as I told you, it requires some amount of code.