# Converting a collection of objects in a non-terminating stream into an IObservable

Tags: c#, stream, json.net, deserialization, system.reactive

I have a `Stream` containing a collection of objects serialized into JSON, for example:

```
{"Name":"Alice","Age":20}{"Name":"Bob","Age":30}{"Name":"Charlie","Age":35}{"Name":"Danielle","Age":50}...
```

This stream may be very large so I want to process the items as they come in rather than reading the entire stream into a string. Also if the stream is a network stream it be open indefinitely.

Some of the objects may be quite complex so I would like to take advantage of the JSON serialization provided by JSON.NET.

Is there a way I can use Newtonsoft Json to convert the stream into an `IObservable<Person>` and process the items reactively as they arrive?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9026821/468244 should give you an idea on how to continuously read from a json stream. Wrapping into a subject/observable/... should not be an issue.

Comment: Would that mean reconstructing the JObject manually from all the tokens? The reader doesn't seem to provide access to the underlying string so I can't see a way to accumulate the text until I hit an EndObject token?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you could modify your input so that it looks like a JSON array, then you could use `JsonTextReader` directly to read the array parts and then use `JsonSerializer` to read the objects inside the array.

This way, the results can be streamed, while you don't have to deal with all the deserialization.

The method producing an `IObservable` could look something like:

```
public static IObservable<T> DeserializeAsObservable<T>(this TextReader reader)
{
    var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader);

    if (!jsonReader.Read() || jsonReader.TokenType != JsonToken.StartArray)
        throw new Exception();

    var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(null);

    return Observable.Create<T>(o => 
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (!jsonReader.Read())
                    o.OnError(new Exception());
                if (jsonReader.TokenType == JsonToken.EndArray)
                    break;
                var obj = serializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonReader);
                o.OnNext(obj);
            }
            o.OnCompleted();
            return Disposable.Empty;
        });
}
```

(Obviously use this only after replacing `new Exception()` with a more suitable exception type.)

Comment: ...and using OnError(...) instead of throwing in the Observable.Create lamba. You may also want to substitute return (IDisposable)null; for return Disposable.Empty;