# Which kind of commpression do I have to use? Or use StreamContent with JsonTextWriter

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, gzipstream

I'm developing an ASP.NET Web Api 2.2 application with .NET Framework 4.5, C# and Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.8.

I have this method to post to this web api:

```
protected bool Post<T>(string completeUri, ref T dataToPost)
{
    bool result = false;

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_webApiHost);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataToPost), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = client.PostAsync(completeUri, content);

        [ ... ]
    }

    return result;
}
```

When I have a lot of data to send I get an Out of Memory exception here:

`HttpContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataToPost), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");`

I have read a lot about compression but I don't know which one do I have to use. I don't know if there are more types but I have found two kinds: IIS compression and [GZip compression](http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-web-api-compression).

Which one do I have to use? If I use GZip compression, do I have to modify my web api client?

**UPDATE:**
I have this class to serialize but I haven't used it:

```
public static string Serialize(Models.Aggregations aggregation)
{
    if (aggregation == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("aggregation");

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    JsonTextWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw);

    writer.WriteStartObject();

    writer.WritePropertyName("Code");
    writer.WriteValue(aggregation.Code);

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(aggregation.Created))
    {
        writer.WritePropertyName("Created");
        writer.WriteValue(aggregation.Created);
    }

    writer.WriteEndObject();

    return sw.ToString();
}
```

It will solve the problem if I use it? I ask this because [@CodeCaster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34392658/68571) has suggested me to use `JsonTextWriter` but I don't know how to use it inside my post method.

**UPDATE 2**
Following [@CodeCaster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34392658/68571) recommendation I'm trying to optimize how I send data to that Web Api and I'm writing my own JSON serializer with this class:

```
public static string Serialize(Models.Aggregations aggregation)
{
    if (aggregation == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("aggregation");

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    JsonTextWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw);

    writer.WriteStartObject();

    writer.WritePropertyName("Code");
    writer.WriteValue(aggregation.Code);

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(aggregation.Created))
    {
        writer.WritePropertyName("Created");
        writer.WriteValue(aggregation.Created);
    }

    writer.WriteEndObject();

    return sw.ToString();
}
```

But [@CodeCaster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34392658/68571) has told me that to make it more efficient I will need to write as a Stream into `StreamContent` using `JsonTextWriter`.

But I don't know how to do that because I don't know how to instantiate `StreamContent`. All the examples that I've seen use a `var stream` but I don't see how they instantiate that object.

How can I use JsonTextWriter to write into the stream?

Comment: Compression will actually make your memory usage MUCH higher. You will need to allocate a buffer for the entire message (which you need to do now), PLUS a buffer for the compressed data. Assuming zero compression, you will end up using twice as much memory.

Comment: @Aron only if you compress everything in-memory, you can also use streams, where the overhead will be just the buffer size.

Comment: @CodeCaster plus the buffer of your original stream. Which again roughly doubles your memory usage.

Comment: @Aron no... if the serializer is streaming you won't have the entire JSON string in memory at once, and if the compressor is streaming then neither. Data will either be not serialized yet, in the process of being serialized or compressed, or compressed already and on the wire. Overall memory usage: lower than when not streaming.

Comment: @CodeCaster My point is that no matter what, adding compression to your stack increases the memory usage from the uncompressed usage. What you are talking about is a completely orthogonal change which requires structural changes to the code.

Comment: @Aron I think so. The changes proposed CodeCaster changes everything on my code.

Answer (score 0):

The compression you're talking about will not solve your problem.

It will only compress the data at the HTTP level. So in your code, you will still get the same, decompressed string, and the same `OutOfMemoryException` which occurs during deserialization.

You need to change how you deserialize the JSON. See [Incremental JSON Parsing in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026508/incremental-json-parsing-in-c-sharp).

Edit: sorry, I read entirely the wrong way around. It's the serialization, not deserialization. Still, same issue. Either the serialization itself, or the instantiation of the `StringContent` throws this exception. You need to serialize it streaming, and directly stream to the output.

So: use `StreamContent`, not `StringContent`, and use `JsonTextWriter` to write into the stream. This way you don't have to have the entire serialized string in memory.

Comment: Compression will actually make his problem worse.

Comment: But, the problem occurs when I serialize a list of objects.

Comment: I have updated my question with another class that uses `JsonTextWriter` but I don't know how to use it inside my post method.

Comment: @Vans the code you show will get you the same exception, as it's still serializing into a string. Serialize into a stream instead.

Comment: Thanks. I'm searching but I don't know how to do it. I don't know how to use JsonTextWriter to serialize to a StreamContent. I have asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34395355/use-jsontextwriter-to-write-into-streamcontent.

Comment: @Vans again, in that question you're showing a method that returns a string. That's never going to work. Please delete that other question and improve this one.

Comment: Again, I don't know how to do it and I haven't found any sample on the web showing how to do that. This is why I haven't changed that class because I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @CodeCaster I have deleted that question and improve this one.

Answer (score 0):

Given `results`  as the `IEnumerable<T>`  containing your objects, you can use JsonTextWriter to write into the response OutputStream in the following way:

```
           // get the response output stream .. 
            using (StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream))
            using (JsonTextWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(stream))
            {
                // .. and use json.net to write the data as json in the stream  
                var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                serializer.Serialize(writer, results);
            }
```

If you have your own `JsonSerializer` you can easily plug it in.

The response content will be compressed and chunked. Fast and neat

```
Response Headers
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Content-Type: application/json
    Content-Encoding: gzip
```