# Will positioned read or seek() from HDFS file load and ignore whole content of the file?

Tags: java, file, hdfs

I want to read sub-content the big file from some offset/position.
For example I have a file of 1M lines and I want to read 50 lines starting from 100th. (line no: 101 to 150 - both inclusive)

I think I should be using PositionalReadable. 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-519

I see that `FSInputStream.readFully` actually uses `seek()` method of `Seekable`.

When I check the underlying implementation of `seek()` I see that it uses `BlockReader.skip()`

Wouldn't the blockReader.skip() read the whole data till position to skip the bytes? Question is would HDFS load first 100 lines as well in order to get to 101th line.

How to make position to be at any desired offset in the file like 10000th line of the file without loading the rest of the content? Something what s3 offers in header-offsets.

Here is the similar question I found: [How to read files with an offset from Hadoop using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24064178/how-to-read-files-with-an-offset-from-hadoop-using-java), but it suggest using `seek()` and that is argued in the comments that `seek()` is expensive operation and should be used sparingly. Which I guess is correct because seek seems to read all the data in order to skip till the position.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer may or may not read as much data as `skip(n)`.
As you said, `seek()` internally calls `BlockReader.skip()`. `BlockReader` is an interface type and is created via `BlockReaderFactory()`. The `BlockReader` implementation that is created is either `BlockReaderRemote` or `BlockReaderLocal`. (Exactly, `ExternalBlockReader` is also possible, but it is excluded because it is a special case)

`BlockReaderRemote` is used when a client reads data from a remote DataNode over the network via RPC over TCP. In this case, if you analyze the `skip()` method code, you can see that `readNextPacket` is repeatedly called as many times as n bytes to skip. **That is, it actually reads the data to be skipped.**

`BlockReaderLocal` is used when the client is on the same machine as the DataNode where the block is stored. In this case, the client can read the block file directly, and change `dataPos` to **actually do an offset-based skip on the next read operation.**

---

+Additional information (2023.01.19)
The above applies to both Hadoop 3.x.x and 2.x.x, but the path and name of the implementation have been changed from version 2.8.0 due to a change in the project structure.

< 2.8.0
hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/BlockReaderLocal.java
hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/RemoteBlockReader.java

>= 2.8.0
hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs-client/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/client/impl/BlockReaderLocal.java
hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs-client/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/client/impl/BlockReaderRemote.java

Related Jira issues
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-8057
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-8925