# Hadoop MapReduce RecordReader Implementation Necessary?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, input-split, recordreader

From the Apache doc on the Hadoop MapReduce [InputFormat](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/InputFormat.html) Interface:

> "**[L]ogical splits based on input-size is insufficient** for many
>   applications since record boundaries are to be respected. In such
>   cases, the application has to also **implement a [RecordReader](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/RecordReader.html)** on
>   whom lies the responsibilty to respect record-boundaries and present a
>   record-oriented view of the logical [InputSplit](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/InputSplit.html) to the individual
>   task."

Is the [WordCount](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Example:_WordCount_v1.0) example application one in which logical splits based on input size are insufficient? If so, where in the source code is the implementation of a RecordReader found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Input splits are logical references to data. If you look at the [API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/InputSplit.html), you can see that it doesn't know anything about the record boundaries. A mapper is launched for every input split. A mapper's `map()` is run for every record(In a WordCount program, every line in a file).

But how does a mapper know where the record boundaries are?

This is where your quote from Hadoop MapReduce [InputFormat](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/InputFormat.html) Interface comes in -

> the application has to also implement a RecordReader on whom lies the
>   responsibilty to respect record-boundaries and present a
>   record-oriented view of the logical InputSplit to the individual task

Every mapper is associated with an InputFormat. That `InputFormat` has information on which `RecordReader` to use. Look at the [API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/InputFormat.html), you will find that it knows about the input splits and what record reader to use.
If you want to know some more about input splits and Record reader, you should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14540272/1101823) answer.

A `RecordReader` defines what the record boundaries are; The `InputFormat` defines what `RecordReader` is used.

The WordCount program does not specify any `InputFormat`, it therefore defaults to `TextInputFormat` which uses [LineRecordReader](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/LineRecordReader.java) and gives out every line as a different record. And [this](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/LineRecordReader.java) your source code

---

> [L]ogical splits based on input-size is insufficient for many
>   applications since record boundaries are to be respected.

What this means is that, for an example file such as

```
a b c d e
f g h i j
k l m n o
```

and we want every line to be a record. when the logical splits are based on input size, it is possible there may be two splits such as:

```
a b c d e
f g
```

and

```
    h i j 
k l m n 0
```

If it wasn't for the `RecordReader`, it would've considered `f g` and `h i j` to be different records; Clearly, this isn't what most applications want.

Answering your question, in the WordCount program, it does not really matter what the record boundaries are but there is a possibility that the same word is split into different logical splits. Therefore, logical splits based on size are not sufficient for WordCount program.

Every MapReduce program 'respects' record boundaries. Otherwise, it is of not much use.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot see the RecorderReader implementation in WordCount Example as it uses default RecordReader and default InputSplit, specified in the framework.

If you want to see their implementation, you can find it in Hadoop Source code.

For more info on Recorder readers and how they work, pl. refer: https://hadoopi.wordpress.com/2013/05/27/understand-recordreader-inputsplit/