# json parsing during download

Tags: android, json, parsing

Is it possible to parse json in parts when it was still downloaded?
For example I load a long json array with a very slow Internet. Can I download a part of text, parse it, add to screen, download next part and so on?

Comment: Jackson provide streaming reading & writing option for JSON  http://jackson.codehaus.org/

Comment: i don't think it's possible, parsing a part of  json string will likely generate Exception only.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the following [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444380/is-there-a-streaming-api-for-json) it has a few answers, but generally the consensus seems to be that you can depending on the package you are using. I have used GSON (Mentioned in the answers) but have never tried the incremental streaming feature.

[GSON](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/) makes a lot of things much easier in general though, so I would check that out first if the other things GSON offers seem like a plus to whatever you are trying to do.