# JSON-encoding very long iterators

Tags: python, json

I am writing a web service which returns objects containing very long lists, encoded in JSON. Of course we want to use iterators rather than Python lists so we can stream the objects from a database; unfortunately, the JSON encoder in the standard library (`json.JSONEncoder`) only accepts lists and tuples to be converted to JSON lists (though `_iterencode_list` looks like it would actually work on any iterable).

The docstrings suggest overriding default to convert the object to a list, but this means we lose the benefits of streaming. Previously, we overrode a private method, but (as could have been expected) that broke when the encoder was refactored.

What is the best way to serialize iterators as JSON lists in Python in a streaming way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I needed exactly this. First approach was override the `JSONEncoder.iterencode()` method. However this does not work because as soon as the iterator is not toplevel, the internals of some `_iterencode()` function take over.

After some studying of the code, I found a very hacky solution, but it works. Python 3 only, but I'm sure the same magic is possible with python 2 (just other magic-method names):

```
import collections.abc
import json
import itertools
import sys
import resource
import time
starttime = time.time()
lasttime = None


def log_memory():
    if "linux" in sys.platform.lower():
        to_MB = 1024
    else:
        to_MB = 1024 * 1024
    print("Memory: %.1f MB, time since start: %.1f sec%s" % (
        resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss / to_MB,
        time.time() - starttime,
        "; since last call: %.1f sec" % (time.time() - lasttime) if lasttime
        else "",
    ))
    globals()["lasttime"] = time.time()


class IterEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    """
    JSON Encoder that encodes iterators as well.
    Write directly to file to use minimal memory
    """
    class FakeListIterator(list):
        def __init__(self, iterable):
            self.iterable = iter(iterable)
            try:
                self.firstitem = next(self.iterable)
                self.truthy = True
            except StopIteration:
                self.truthy = False

        def __iter__(self):
            if not self.truthy:
                return iter([])
            return itertools.chain([self.firstitem], self.iterable)

        def __len__(self):
            raise NotImplementedError("Fakelist has no length")

        def __getitem__(self, i):
            raise NotImplementedError("Fakelist has no getitem")

        def __setitem__(self, i):
            raise NotImplementedError("Fakelist has no setitem")

        def __bool__(self):
            return self.truthy

    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, collections.abc.Iterable):
            return type(self).FakeListIterator(o)
        return super().default(o)

print(json.dumps((i for i in range(10)), cls=IterEncoder))
print(json.dumps((i for i in range(0)), cls=IterEncoder))
print(json.dumps({"a": (i for i in range(10))}, cls=IterEncoder))
print(json.dumps({"a": (i for i in range(0))}, cls=IterEncoder))


log_memory()
print("dumping 10M numbers as incrementally")
with open("/dev/null", "wt") as fp:
    json.dump(range(10000000), fp, cls=IterEncoder)
log_memory()
print("dumping 10M numbers built in encoder")
with open("/dev/null", "wt") as fp:
    json.dump(list(range(10000000)), fp)
log_memory()
```

Results:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[]
{"a": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]}
{"a": []}
Memory: 8.4 MB, time since start: 0.0 sec
dumping 10M numbers as incrementally
Memory: 9.0 MB, time since start: 8.6 sec; since last call: 8.6 sec
dumping 10M numbers built in encoder
Memory: 395.5 MB, time since start: 17.1 sec; since last call: 8.5 sec
```

It's clear to see that the IterEncoder does not need the memory to store 10M ints, while keeping the same encoding speed.

The (hacky) trick is that the `_iterencode_list` actually doesn't need any of the list things. It just wants to know if the list is empty (`__bool__`) and then get its iterator. However it only gets to this code when `isinstance(x, (list, tuple))` returns True. So I'm packaging the iterator into a list-subclass, then disabling all the random-access, getting the first element up front so that I know whether it's empty or not, and feeding back the iterator. Then the `default` method returns this fake list in case of an iterator.

Comment: +1 It is an excellent solution that inspired me to write a similar shorter variant of FakeListIterator in my [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46841935/448474). It doesn't need to raise exceptions and everything works seamlessly including `__len__`, `__bool__`, `__repr__` etc. that are not overridden.

Comment: btw if you are only overriding the `default` method  of `JSONEncoder` you don't need to subclass it, just define a function and pass it to the  `default` kwarg of `json.dumps(obj, default=...)`

Comment: This solution has more value than I can describe here! I'm working with data sets and wanted to transfer data of varying size from small into huge to a Databricks DBFS via API. JSON-encoding the stream and making add_block()-calls solves my max. 1 MiB per chunk -problem efficiently. Thank you @Claude!

Answer (score 2):

Save this into a module file and import it or paste it directly into your code.

```
'''
Copied from Python 2.7.8 json.encoder lib, diff follows:
@@ -331,6 +331,8 @@
                     chunks = _iterencode(value, _current_indent_level)
                 for chunk in chunks:
                     yield chunk
+        if first:
+            yield buf
         if newline_indent is not None:
             _current_indent_level -= 1
             yield '\n' + (' ' * (_indent * _current_indent_level))
@@ -427,12 +429,12 @@
             yield str(o)
         elif isinstance(o, float):
             yield _floatstr(o)
-        elif isinstance(o, (list, tuple)):
-            for chunk in _iterencode_list(o, _current_indent_level):
-                yield chunk
         elif isinstance(o, dict):
             for chunk in _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level):
                 yield chunk
+        elif hasattr(o, '__iter__'):
+            for chunk in _iterencode_list(o, _current_indent_level):
+                yield chunk
         else:
             if markers is not None:
                 markerid = id(o)
'''
from json import encoder

def _make_iterencode(markers, _default, _encoder, _indent, _floatstr,
        _key_separator, _item_separator, _sort_keys, _skipkeys, _one_shot,
        ## HACK: hand-optimized bytecode; turn globals into locals
        ValueError=ValueError,
        basestring=basestring,
        dict=dict,
        float=float,
        id=id,
        int=int,
        isinstance=isinstance,
        list=list,
        long=long,
        str=str,
        tuple=tuple,
    ):

    def _iterencode_list(lst, _current_indent_level):
        if not lst:
            yield '[]'
            return
        if markers is not None:
            markerid = id(lst)
            if markerid in markers:
                raise ValueError("Circular reference detected")
            markers[markerid] = lst
        buf = '['
        if _indent is not None:
            _current_indent_level += 1
            newline_indent = '\n' + (' ' * (_indent * _current_indent_level))
            separator = _item_separator + newline_indent
            buf += newline_indent
        else:
            newline_indent = None
            separator = _item_separator
        first = True
        for value in lst:
            if first:
                first = False
            else:
                buf = separator
            if isinstance(value, basestring):
                yield buf + _encoder(value)
            elif value is None:
                yield buf + 'null'
            elif value is True:
                yield buf + 'true'
            elif value is False:
                yield buf + 'false'
            elif isinstance(value, (int, long)):
                yield buf + str(value)
            elif isinstance(value, float):
                yield buf + _floatstr(value)
            else:
                yield buf
                if isinstance(value, (list, tuple)):
                    chunks = _iterencode_list(value, _current_indent_level)
                elif isinstance(value, dict):
                    chunks = _iterencode_dict(value, _current_indent_level)
                else:
                    chunks = _iterencode(value, _current_indent_level)
                for chunk in chunks:
                    yield chunk
        if first:
            yield buf
        if newline_indent is not None:
            _current_indent_level -= 1
            yield '\n' + (' ' * (_indent * _current_indent_level))
        yield ']'
        if markers is not None:
            del markers[markerid]

    def _iterencode_dict(dct, _current_indent_level):
        if not dct:
            yield '{}'
            return
        if markers is not None:
            markerid = id(dct)
            if markerid in markers:
                raise ValueError("Circular reference detected")
            markers[markerid] = dct
        yield '{'
        if _indent is not None:
            _current_indent_level += 1
            newline_indent = '\n' + (' ' * (_indent * _current_indent_level))
            item_separator = _item_separator + newline_indent
            yield newline_indent
        else:
            newline_indent = None
            item_separator = _item_separator
        first = True
        if _sort_keys:
            items = sorted(dct.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[0])
        else:
            items = dct.iteritems()
        for key, value in items:
            if isinstance(key, basestring):
                pass
            # JavaScript is weakly typed for these, so it makes sense to
            # also allow them.  Many encoders seem to do something like this.
            elif isinstance(key, float):
                key = _floatstr(key)
            elif key is True:
                key = 'true'
            elif key is False:
                key = 'false'
            elif key is None:
                key = 'null'
            elif isinstance(key, (int, long)):
                key = str(key)
            elif _skipkeys:
                continue
            else:
                raise TypeError("key " + repr(key) + " is not a string")
            if first:
                first = False
            else:
                yield item_separator
            yield _encoder(key)
            yield _key_separator
            if isinstance(value, basestring):
                yield _encoder(value)
            elif value is None:
                yield 'null'
            elif value is True:
                yield 'true'
            elif value is False:
                yield 'false'
            elif isinstance(value, (int, long)):
                yield str(value)
            elif isinstance(value, float):
                yield _floatstr(value)
            else:
                if isinstance(value, (list, tuple)):
                    chunks = _iterencode_list(value, _current_indent_level)
                elif isinstance(value, dict):
                    chunks = _iterencode_dict(value, _current_indent_level)
                else:
                    chunks = _iterencode(value, _current_indent_level)
                for chunk in chunks:
                    yield chunk
        if newline_indent is not None:
            _current_indent_level -= 1
            yield '\n' + (' ' * (_indent * _current_indent_level))
        yield '}'
        if markers is not None:
            del markers[markerid]

    def _iterencode(o, _current_indent_level):
        if isinstance(o, basestring):
            yield _encoder(o)
        elif o is None:
            yield 'null'
        elif o is True:
            yield 'true'
        elif o is False:
            yield 'false'
        elif isinstance(o, (int, long)):
            yield str(o)
        elif isinstance(o, float):
            yield _floatstr(o)
        elif isinstance(o, dict):
            for chunk in _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level):
                yield chunk
        elif hasattr(o, '__iter__'):
            for chunk in _iterencode_list(o, _current_indent_level):
                yield chunk
        else:
            if markers is not None:
                markerid = id(o)
                if markerid in markers:
                    raise ValueError("Circular reference detected")
                markers[markerid] = o
            o = _default(o)
            for chunk in _iterencode(o, _current_indent_level):
                yield chunk
            if markers is not None:
                del markers[markerid]

    return _iterencode

encoder._make_iterencode = _make_iterencode
```

Answer (score -1):

Real streaming is not well supported by `json`, as it would also mean that the client application too will have to support streaming. There are some java libraries that support reading a streamed `json` streams, but is is not very generic. There are also some python bindings for `yail`, which is a C library wich supports streaming.

Maybe you can use `Yaml` instead of `json`. `Yaml` is a superset of json. It has better support for streaming on both sides and any `json` message will still be valid `yaml`.

But in your case it may much be simpler to split your object stream into a stream of separate `json` messages.

See also this discussion here, which client libraries support streaming: [Is there a streaming API for JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444380/is-there-a-streaming-api-for-json)

Comment: The question *Is there a streaming API for JSON?* is about parsing JSON not creating it.

Comment: This is simply not True: "it would also mean that the client application will have to support streaming".
On the server side you might care about memory footprint, while on the client you are ok with keeping the full object in memory..

Comment: How would you stream a partial list from a server to a client that does not support streaming?

Comment: @HansThen Perhaps the server momentarily holds the text JSON representation, but that doesn't mean that it must also store a materialised list of the iterable from which it was generated. Perhaps the server even manages to stream the JSON representation (and doesn't have to hold it all in memory) and something on the network handles the buffering for the client.

Answer (score -2):

Not that simple. The WSGI(which is what most people use) protocol does not support streaming. And the servers that do support it, are violating the spec.

And even if you use a non-compliant server, then you have to use something like [ijson](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ijson/).
Also take a look at this guy who had the same problem as you http://www.enricozini.org/2011/tips/python-stream-json/

**EDIT:** Then it all comes down to the client, which I suppose it will be written in Javascript(?). But I don't see how you could construct javascript(or whatever language) objects out of incomplete
JSON chuncks. The only thing I can think of, is manually breaking down the long JSON into smaller JSON objects(on the server side) and then stream it, one by one to the client. But this calls for websockets and not for stateless http requests/responses. And if by web service you mean a REST API, then I guess it's not what you want.

Comment: My question really has nothing to do with WSGI. ijson is a parser, not an encoder.

Comment: Nothing in PEP 3333 (the WSGI protocol) prohibits streaming responses. The only stipulation is that the WSGI server must not internally buffer or block once it starts writing to the client. Most WSGI servers just continually call fflush(3) or comparable abstraction on the output socket on receipt of a bytestream from the application, so it is perfectly acceptable to iterate over a generator (the yielded object is immediately sent to the socket after serialization).