# Efficiency of open a very big JSONArray (in a file), just to see first position

Tags: java, android, json

I'm reading a JSON file in my android project, just to see the first position of the array.

In fact, if this JSON is more big what normal, I think this isn't efficient...

My json file reader:

```
public static JSONObject parseJSONfromInputStrem (InputStreamReader isr){
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr,8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        isr.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;
}
```

Where I call the function:

```
 FileInputStream fis = c.openFileInput(file);
 InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
 JSONObject jso = JSONParser.parseJSONfromInputStrem(isr);
 JSONArray myArray = jso.getJSONArray("data");
```

There are any way to read, efficiently, the first position of a JSONArray?

Comment: Why don't you just read the first few lines of the stream and parse it yourself...? Most parsers will parse the entire JSON for you. If you don't need it, don't use it

Comment: Please don't wrong your own JSON parser...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a streaming JSON parser (think DOM vs SAX).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/823632/18573 lists some. There may be others.

Answer (score 0):

You can either read in a small amount of the file and pull the value out manually, or put the value in to a separate file.  Even if it's duplicated data, a secondary file which contains summarized or key information from the primary file will make things much more efficient.