# How do I use the 'json' module to read in one JSON object at a time?

Tags: python, json

I have a multi-gigabyte JSON file. The file is made up of JSON objects that are no more than a few thousand characters each, but there are no line breaks between the records.

Using Python 3 and the `json` module, how can I read one JSON object at a time from the file into memory?

The data is in a plain text file. Here is an example of a similar record.  The actual records contains many nested dictionaries and lists.

Record in readable format:

```
{
    "results": {
      "__metadata": {
        "type": "DataServiceProviderDemo.Address"
      },
      "Street": "NE 228th",
      "City": "Sammamish",
      "State": "WA",
      "ZipCode": "98074",
      "Country": "USA"
    }
  }
}
```

Actual format. New records start one after the other without any breaks.

```
{"results": { "__metadata": {"type": "DataServiceProviderDemo.Address"},"Street": "NE 228th","City": "Sammamish","State": "WA","ZipCode": "98074","Country": "USA" } } }{"results": { "__metadata": {"type": "DataServiceProviderDemo.Address"},"Street": "NE 228th","City": "Sammamish","State": "WA","ZipCode": "98074","Country": "USA" } } }{"results": { "__metadata": {"type": "DataServiceProviderDemo.Address"},"Street": "NE 228th","City": "Sammamish","State": "WA","ZipCode": "98074","Country": "USA" } } }
```

Comment: Post a sample of the data, at least few *objects*.

Comment: You mean the JSON file is an array of objects, and you want to lazily read those objects?

Comment: And did you already search for other posts on this very subject, here on Stack Overflow? There is at least one listed in the 'related' sidebar here that I can see. How did those posts not address your specific situation?

Comment: @poke I'm not sure what you mean by 'lazily', but yes I think that is what I want.

Comment: @MartijnPieters None of the other posts I could find addressed the same problem. Could you share the link with the solution you found?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a [streaming JSON parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444380/is-there-a-streaming-api-for-json) *for Python*, which I can't find a duplicate of on SO, so I think it's a legit question.

Comment: @user3281420: As it turns out, there is no answer that handles this specific case. But that was only apparent after you updated the post a little. :-)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Generally speaking, putting more than one JSON object into a file makes that file *invalid, broken JSON*. That said, you can still parse data in chunks using the [`JSONDecoder.raw_decode()` method](http://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONDecoder.raw_decode).

The following will yield complete objects as the parser finds them:

```
from json import JSONDecoder
from functools import partial


def json_parse(fileobj, decoder=JSONDecoder(), buffersize=2048):
    buffer = ''
    for chunk in iter(partial(fileobj.read, buffersize), ''):
         buffer += chunk
         while buffer:
             try:
                 result, index = decoder.raw_decode(buffer)
                 yield result
                 buffer = buffer[index:].lstrip()
             except ValueError:
                 # Not enough data to decode, read more
                 break
```

This function will read chunks from the given file object in `buffersize` chunks, and have the `decoder` object parse whole JSON objects from the buffer. Each parsed object is yielded to the caller.

Use it like this:

```
with open('yourfilename', 'r') as infh:
    for data in json_parse(infh):
        # process object
```

Use this only if your JSON objects are written to a file back-to-back, with no newlines in between. If you *do* have newlines, and each JSON object is limited to a single line, you have a [JSON Lines document](http://jsonlines.org/), in which case you can use [Loading and parsing a JSON file with multiple JSON objects in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451431/loading-parsing-json-file-in-python/12451465#12451465) instead.

Comment: This worked great, thank you.  Yes, the file i was dealing with had back to back JSON objects.  Also for the try/except, I used 'pass' instead of 'break'.  Was the break intentional?  I couldn't get it to work with it.

Comment: @user3281420: yes, the `break` was intentional; it breaks the `while` loop so we move on the next chunk read from the file. The `break` is only triggered if there is no JSON object to decode in the current buffer.

Comment: @user3281420: `pass` would only work if the buffer was empty as that is the other termination condition for the `while` loop.

Comment: @user3281420: If you are willing to share a file that doesn't work when `break` is used, I'd love to see if I can debug it. Have a dropbox link for me perhaps?

Comment: Hrm perhaps I gave a bad example of the data.  Sorry, I don't think I can share this data.  When I was using a break the script would exit before doing any of the processing on the json data.  Thanks for the code though.  I learned a lot just trying to figure out what It was doing.

Comment: non standard way is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21855877/parse-2-json-strings-in-python/21856188 which with some editing migt be useful to get rid of rubbish data between the jsons (new lines / any separators)

Comment: @RonanDejhero: it's easy enough to add a `.strip()` call to the `buffer`: `result, index = decoder.raw_decode(buffer.strip())` to remove whitespace, `buffer.strip(' \n|')` to remove an explicit set of characters.

Comment: How do you extract a key-value from this 'data' variable?

Comment: @user2441441: `data` is the JSON data decoded to a Python object. It depends on what JSON object you decoded how to get key-value pairs from it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters' comment suggesting `decoder.raw_decode(buffer.strip())` will produce an incorrect index for `buffer = buffer[index:]`. You need `buffer = buffer.lstrip()` before calling raw_decode`

Comment: @Willem: ah, indeed, the index would be into the stripped buffer, not the original.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a slight modification of [Martijn Pieters' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21709058/190597), which will handle JSON strings separated with whitespace.

```
def json_parse(fileobj, decoder=json.JSONDecoder(), buffersize=2048, 
               delimiters=None):
    remainder = ''
    for chunk in iter(functools.partial(fileobj.read, buffersize), ''):
        remainder += chunk
        while remainder:
            try:
                stripped = remainder.strip(delimiters)
                result, index = decoder.raw_decode(stripped)
                yield result
                remainder = stripped[index:]
            except ValueError:
                # Not enough data to decode, read more
                break
```

---

[For example,](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27027395/190597) if `data.txt` contains JSON strings separated by a space:

```
{"business_id": "1", "Accepts Credit Cards": true, "Price Range": 1, "type": "food"} {"business_id": "2", "Accepts Credit Cards": true, "Price Range": 2, "type": "cloth"} {"business_id": "3", "Accepts Credit Cards": false, "Price Range": 3, "type": "sports"}
```

then

```
In [47]: list(json_parse(open('data')))
Out[47]: 
[{u'Accepts Credit Cards': True,
  u'Price Range': 1,
  u'business_id': u'1',
  u'type': u'food'},
 {u'Accepts Credit Cards': True,
  u'Price Range': 2,
  u'business_id': u'2',
  u'type': u'cloth'},
 {u'Accepts Credit Cards': False,
  u'Price Range': 3,
  u'business_id': u'3',
  u'type': u'sports'}]
```

Answer (score 6):

If your JSON documents contains a list of objects, and you want to read one object one-at-a-time, you can use the iterative JSON parser *[ijson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ijson/)* for the job. It will only read more content from the file when it needs to decode the next object.

Note that you should use it with the [YAJL](http://lloyd.github.io/yajl/) library, otherwise you will likely not see any performance increase.

That being said, unless your file is *really big*, reading it completely into memory and then parsing it with the normal JSON module will probably still be the best option.