# Load multiple JSON objects from the same file in Python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to extract multiple objects from the same JSON file. My JSON file content looks something like this:

```
{"business_id": "1",
 "Accepts Credit Cards": true,
 "Price Range": 1,
 "type": "food"}
{"business_id": "2",
 "Accepts Credit Cards": true,
 "Price Range": 2,
 "type": "cloth"}
{"business_id": "3",
 "Accepts Credit Cards": false,
 "Price Range": 3,
 "type": "sports"}
```

I am trying the below code which works fine for a file containing only one JSON object.

```
import json

with open("business.json") as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)
    print(json_data)
```

How can I solve this problem? I did not find any solution for parsing JSON data from the same file.

Comment: Are you allowed fix your file?  If you changed your file to be an array of json objects, it would work fine.

Comment: The file is not valid JSON as a whole.  One simple solution would be to put `[` and the beginning of the file and `]` at the end to make it one big array.  Then you could parse it as JSON and extract the individual pieces.

Comment: You'd need a couple of commas too :)

Comment: And there are more closing braces than opening braces...

Comment: @BrenBarn this is a small part of the whole object. The one I have used is valid as it works for single object. But it does not work for multiple JSON. Making it a list is not possible as there are total 70k objects like that.

Comment: @unutbu would this work for the below data? Actually I took an example of multiple JSON objects in the same file. but the code which parse one object per file does not work for multiple objects in the same file {"business_id": "1", "Accepts Credit Cards": true, "Price Range": 1, "type": "food"} {"business_id": "2", "Accepts Credit Cards": true, "Price Range": 2, "type": "cloth"} {"business_id": "3", "Accepts Credit Cards": false, "Price Range": 3, "type": "sports"}

Comment: The linked solution works when the JSON strings are concatenated with no whitespace in between. The solution can be made to work when there are spaces by stripping the `buffer` before decoding. I've posted the [code to do this here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27040050/190597).