# How to find JSON object in text with python

Tags: python, json, regex

I'm trying to parse JSON object from text with python regex. I found this match:

```
'\{(?:[^{}]|(?R))*\}'
```

but in python I get this error:

```
re.error: unknown extension ?R at position 12
```

See the regex match in [this regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/yZ9fO6/1).

Comment: That's because that's not syntax supported by the Python regex parser. There is no universal regex syntax standard supported by all engines.

Comment: Bottom line: don't just copy regex patterns from random locations and expect them to work in random regex engines. At a minimum [educate yourself a little about regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/). Recursion is supported in [Perl, Ruby and and languages that use the PRCE library](https://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html), other languages need to use 3rd-party libraries, if available.

Answer (score 38):

You found a regex that uses syntax that Python standard library `re` module doesn't support.

When you look at the regex101 link, you'll see that the pattern works when using the [PRCE library](https://www.regular-expressions.info/pcre.html), and the problematic `(?R)` syntax that throws the error uses a feature called [*recursion*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html). That feature is only supported by a [subset of regex engines](https://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html).

You could install the [`regex` library](https://pypi.org/project/regex/), an alternative regex engine for Python that explicitly does support that syntax:

```
>>> import regex
>>> pattern = regex.compile(r'\{(?:[^{}]|(?R))*\}')
>>> pattern.findall('''\
... This is a funny text about stuff,
... look at this product {"action":"product","options":{...}}.
... More Text is to come and another JSON string
... {"action":"review","options":{...}}
... ''')
['{"action":"product","options":{...}}', '{"action":"review","options":{...}}']
```

Another option is to just try and decode any section that starts with `{` using the [`JSONDecoder.raw_decode()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONDecoder.raw_decode); see [How do I use the 'json' module to read in one JSON object at a time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708192/how-do-i-use-the-json-module-to-read-in-one-json-object-at-a-time/21709058#21709058) for an example approach. While the recursive regex can find JSON-*like* text, the decoder approach would let you extract only *valid* JSON text.

Here is a generator function that does just that:

```
from json import JSONDecoder

def extract_json_objects(text, decoder=JSONDecoder()):
    """Find JSON objects in text, and yield the decoded JSON data

    Does not attempt to look for JSON arrays, text, or other JSON types outside
    of a parent JSON object.

    """
    pos = 0
    while True:
        match = text.find('{', pos)
        if match == -1:
            break
        try:
            result, index = decoder.raw_decode(text[match:])
            yield result
            pos = match + index
        except ValueError:
            pos = match + 1
```

Demo:

```
>>> demo_text = """\
This is a funny text about stuff,
look at this product {"action":"product","options":{"foo": "bar"}}.
More Text is to come and another JSON string, neatly delimited by "{" and "}" characters:
{"action":"review","options":{"spam": ["ham", "vikings", "eggs", "spam"]}}
"""
>>> for result in extract_json_objects(demo_text):
...     print(result)
...
{'action': 'product', 'options': {'foo': 'bar'}}
{'action': 'review', 'options': {'spam': ['ham', 'vikings', 'eggs', 'spam']}}
```

Comment: If it's useful, I Frankenstein'ed `extract_json_objects()` to also provide the surrounding text, so that a user could choose to json-prettify the objects along with the string which contained it. [Adam can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61384796/1431750).

Answer (score 4):

If there is only one JSON in one line, you can use the index methods to find the first and the last bracket to select the JSON:

```
firstValue = jsonString.index("{")
lastValue = len(jsonString) - jsonString[::-1].index("}")
jsonString = jsonStringEncoded[firstValue:lastValue]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thas is because python `re` module is pretty weak and do not support subroutines and recursion. Try [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) `regex` module instead. It will compile your regex.