# How to convert this json file to pandas dataframe

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

The format in the file looks like this

{ 'match' : 'a', 'score' : '2'},{......}

I've tried pd.DataFrame and I've also tried reading it by line but it gives me everything in one cell

I'm new to python

Thanks in advance

Expected result is a pandas dataframe

Comment: Do the columns always match? I.E. Is the JSON file {'match': 'a', 'score': '2'}, {'match':'b', 'score':'3'}? Or do the dictionaries have different key-value pairs?

Comment: Please, don't forget to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) one of the answer, @bsa1player.

Answer (score 0):

Try use [json_normalize()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) function

Example:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

values = [{'match': 'a', 'score': '2'}, {'match': 'b', 'score': '3'}, {'match': 'c', 'score': '4'}]
df = json_normalize(values)
print(df)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If one line of your file corresponds to one JSON object, you can do the following:

```
# import library for working with JSON and pandas
import json 
import pandas as pd

# make an empty list
data = []

# open your file and add every row as a dict to the list with data
with open("/path/to/your/file", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        data.append(json.loads(line))

# make a pandas data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

If there is more than only one JSON object on one row of your file, then you should find those JSON objects, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54235528/how-to-find-json-object-in-text-with-python) are two possible options. The solution with the second option would look like this:

```
# import all you will need
import pandas as pd
import json
from json import JSONDecoder

# define function
def extract_json_objects(text, decoder=JSONDecoder()):
    pos = 0
    while True:
        match = text.find('{', pos)
        if match == -1:
            break
        try:
            result, index = decoder.raw_decode(text[match:])
            yield result
            pos = match + index
        except ValueError:
            pos = match + 1

# make an empty list
data = []

# open your file and add every JSON object as a dict to the list with data
with open("/path/to/your/file", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        for item in extract_json_objects(line):
            data.append(item)

# make a pandas data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```