# TypeError: raw_decode() missing 1 required positional argument: 's'

Tags: python, json

This is my first question here, so I thank everyone in advance for your patience...

I am trying to understand [the solution with *JSONDecoder* for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54235803/6235116), and to learn at the same time how does *raw_decode* work.

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders):

> raw_decode(s)
>
> Decode a JSON document from s (a str beginning with a JSON document) and return a 2-tuple of the Python representation and the index in s where the document ended.
>
> This can be used to decode a JSON document from a string that may have
> extraneous data at the end.

I have a string beginning with a JSON document:

```
text = '{"param1":"1","param2":"2"} some other text'
```

And I'm trying to get from it a JSON document:

```
result, index = json.JSONDecoder.raw_decode(text)
```

Get

```
TypeError: raw_decode() missing 1 required positional argument: 's'
```

What am I missing? Where do I get it wrong?
Thanks in advance for the answers!

Comment: It's an *instance* method, not a class method. You need an instance before you can call that method. `d = JSONDecoder(); d.raw_decode(text)`.

Comment: @deceze thanks a lot for your instant answer! I understand that I lack basic python knowledge, but how can I understand from the documentation - is it instance or class method?

Comment: Class methods are the exception, not the rule, in Python. Unless the docs explicitly say something is a class method, it's an instance method.