# How to structure (take out) JSON from a text string. (Python)

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text string/script which I took out from a webpage. I would like to clean/structure that text string/Script so that I can only get JSON out of it. But its very long that I lost finding beginning and ending of JSON from that text. Does anyone help me out or advice a online website which can help to find the beginning and ending of JSON from that text. Many Thanks

```
window.__NUXT__=function(e,l,a,t,r,s,i,o,n,d){return{layout:s,data:[{product:{active_gtin:"5711555000616",active_supplier:"0000009002",active_supplier_product_id:"000000000091052931-EA",brand:"Prosonic",description:"Prosonic 32\" TV med Android og Full-HD opløsning. Android styresystemet giver dig let adgang til Netflix, Viaplay og TV2 Play samt mange andre apps og med indbygget Chromecast kan du let caste indhold til TV'et.",display_list_price:l,display_sales_price:l,energy_class:"A+",energy_class_color_code:"lev_3",energy_label:i,erp_product_id:o,gallery_images:[i,"https://sg-dam.imgix.net/services/assets.img/id/13a13e85-efe7-48eb-bb6c-953abc94fb08/size/original","https://sg-dam.imgix.net/services/assets.img/id/e0c39be1-eb82-4652-88f4-992226390a3f/size/original","https://sg-dam.imgix.net/services/assets.img/id/9bc81449-64ba-44c0-b691-31b22bf5dc91/size/original"],hybris_code:n,id:n,image_primary:"https://sg-dam.imgix.net/services/assets.img/id/f8d59494-3da7-4cb7-9dd8-e8d16577e7c4/size/original",in_stock_stores_count:15,is_approved_for_sale:t,is_exposed:t,is_reservable:t,name:'Prosonic 32" 32and6021 LED tv',online_from:16000344e5,online_to:2534022108e5,primary_category_path:"/elektronik/tv",product_url:"/produkter/prosonic-32-32and6021-led-tv/100553115/",sales_price:e,show_discount_message:a,sku:o,specifications:'[{"features":[{"code":"text-TvMemory","label":"Tekst TV hukommelse","value":"1000"}],"label":"Tekst TV hukommelse"},{"features":[{"code":"tvFeatures","label":"TV funktioner","value":"Netflix"},{"code":"tvFeatures","label":"TV funktioner","value":"SmartTV"},{"code":"tvFeatures","label":"TV funktioner","value":"Wi-Fi indbygget"}],"label":"TV funktioner"},{"features":[{"code":"TV.tvApps","label":"TV Apps","value":"Amazon"},{"code":"TV.tvApps","label":"TV Apps","value":"Apple TV"},{"code":"TV.tvApps","label":"TV Apps","value":"Blockbuster"},{"code":"TV.tvApps","label":"TV Apps","value":"Boxer"},{"code":"TV.tvApps","label":"TV Apps","value":"Dplay"},{"code":"TV.tvApps","label":"TV Apps","value":"DR TV"},{"code":"TV.tvApps","label":"TV Apps","value":"Google Play Store"},{"code":"TV.tvApps","label":"TV Apps","value":"HBO Nordic"},{"code":"TV.tvApps","label":"TV Apps","value":"Min Bio"},{"code":"TV.tvApps","label":"TV Apps","value":"Netflix"},{"code":"TV.tvApps","label":"TV Apps","value":"Rakuten TV"},{"code":"TV.tvApps","label":"TV Apps","value":"SF Anytime"},{"code":"TV.tvApps","label":"TV Apps","value":"Skype"},{"code":"TV.tvApps","label":"TV Apps","value":"Spotify"},{"code":"TV.tvApps","label":"TV Apps","value":"TV2 play"},{"code":"TV.tvApps","label":"TV Apps","value":"Viaplay"},{"code":"TV.tvApps","label":"TV Apps","value":"YouSee"},{"code":"TV.tvApps","label":"TV Apps","value":"Youtube"}],"label":"TV Apps"},{"features":[{"code":"connectivity.videoConnectivity","label":"Video tilslutning","value":"composite"}],"label":"Video tilslutning"},{"features":[{"code":"screen.monitorLanguageList","label":"Skærmsprog","value":"Dansk"}],"label":"Skærmsprog"},{"features":[{"code":"builtInSpeakers.soundFunction","label":"Lydfunktioner","value":"Bluetooth"}],"label":"Lydfunktioner"},{"features":[{"code":"productionYear","label":"Produktionsår","value":"2.020"}],"label":"Produktionsår"},{"features":[{"code":"electronics.manufacturerNum","label":"Producentens Varenummer","value":"32AND6021"}],"label":"Producentens Varenummer"},{"features":[{"code":"TV.hdrLOV","label":"HDR","value":"HDR 10"}],"label":"HDR"},{"features":[{"code":"TV.isSleepTimerPresent","label":"Sleep timer","value":"Ja"}],"label":"Sleep timer"},{"features":[{"code":"isPVRFunctionPresent","label":"PVR funktion","value":"Ja"}],"label":"PVR funktion"},{"features":[{"code":"accessoriesIncluded","label":"Tilbehør inkluderet","value":"stand og remote"}],"label":"Tilbehør inkluderet"},{"features":[{"code":"screenTechnologyDesc","label":"Skærmteknologi","value":"LED"}],"label":"Skærmteknologi"},{"features":[{"code":"tvTunerList","label":"TV-tuners","value":"CI+"},{"code":"tvTunerList","label":"TV-tuners","value":"DVB-C"},{"code":"tvTunerList","label":"TV-tuners","value":"DVB-S"},{"code":"tvTunerList","label":"TV-tuners","value":"DVB-T2"},{"code":"tvTunerList","label":"TV-tuners","value":"MPEG4 tuner"}],"label":"TV-tuners"},{"features":[{"code":"TV.vesaStandardList","label":"Vægbeslag Vesa standard","value":"75x75"}],"label":"Vægbeslag Vesa standard"},{"features":[{"code":"connectivity.hdmiCount","label":"Antal HDMI","value":"3"}],"label":"Antal HDMI"},{"features":[{"code":"builtInSpeakers.speakerEffect","label":"Højtalereffekt","value":"12"}],"label":"Højtalereffekt"},{"features":[{"code":"usbCount","label":"Antal USB stik","value":"1"}],"label":"Antal USB stik"},{"features":[{"code":"TVResolution","label":"TV opløsning","value":"Full HD"}],"label":"TV opløsning"},{"features":[{"code":"picturePlayers.supportedImageFormats","label":"Understøttede Billed Formater","value":"JPG,BMP,PNG,GIF"}],"label":"Understøttede Billed Formater"},{"features":[{"code":"scartCount","label":"Antal scartstik","value":"0"}],"label":"Antal scartstik"},{"features":[{"code":"connectivity.usbcount2","label":"Antal USB 2.0 porte","value":"1"}],"label":"Antal USB 2.0 porte"},{"features":[{"code":"Color","label":"Produktfarve","value":"sort"}],"label":"Produktfarve"},{"features":[{"code":"TV.isWatchAndTimerFunctionOnOffPresent","label":"Ur og timerfunktion til\\/fra","value":"Ja"}],"label":"Ur og timerfunktion til\\/fra"},{"features":[{"code":"TV.isAutomaticChannelSearchAvailable","label":"Automatisk kanalsøgning","value":"Ja"}],"label":"Automatisk kanalsøgning"},{"features":[{"code":"screen.screenResolution","label":"Skærmopløsning","value":"Full-HD 1920 x 1080"}],"label":"Skærmopløsning"},{"features":[{"code":"TV.software","label":"TV software","value":"Android"}],"label":"TV software"},{"features":[{"code":"connectivity.connectivityDesc","label":"Andre tilslutningsmuligheder","value":"Composite, Audio in, VGA, optisk lyd ud,"}],"label":"Andre tilslutningsmuligheder"},{"features":[{"code":"TV.twinTuner","label":"Twin Tuner","value":"Nej"}],"label":"Twin Tuner"},{"features":[{"code":"picturePlayers.supportedVideoFileFormats","label":"Understøttede videofil formater","value":".MPG .MPEG.DAT.VOB.MKV.MP4 \\/ .M4A \\/ .M4V.MOV.FLV.3GP \\/ 3GPP.TS \\/ .M2TS.RMVB .RM.AVI.ASF .WMV.WEBM"}],"label":"Understøttede videofil formater"},{"features":[{"code":"isInternetBrowserPresent","label":"Internet browser","value":"Ja"}],"label":"Internet browser"},{"features":[{"code":"wirelessConnectivityOptionList","label":"Trådløse tilslutningsmuligheder","value":"Bluetooth"},{"code":"wirelessConnectivityOptionList","label":"Trådløse tilslutningsmuligheder","value":"Wi-Fi indbygget"}],"label":"Trådløse tilslutningsmuligheder"}]',step_product_id:"GR14425172",stock_count_online:2874,stock_count_status_online:"in_stock",stock_type:"NORMAL",summary:"Med Android og indbygget Chromecast",msg_sales_price_per_unit:l,package_display_sales_price:l,promotion_text:e,f_campaign_name:[]},loadingProduct:a}],error:e,state:{User:{UID:l,isLoggedIn:a,nickname:l,address:{firstName:l,lastName:l,address:l,postalCode:l,city:l,mobile:l,email:l,country:l},isDeliveryMethodSet:a,lastSeenProducts:[],wishlistProducts:[]},Tracking:{trackedOrders:[],activeRoute:e,oldRoute:e,cookieConsentGiven:a,initialRouteTracked:a},Search:{showDrawer:a,hideGlobalSearch:a,query:l,queryString:l,queries:[],brands:[],categories:[]},Products:{products:[]},ProductDialog:{showType:a,productId:e,quantity:e,error:e},plugins:{Cart:{checkoutErrorPlugin:{},productDialogPlugin:{}},TechnicalError:{technicalErrorPlugin:{}},Tracking:{gtmPlugin:{},gtmHandlers:{appInitializedHandler:{},bannerClickedHandler:{},bannerViewedHandler:{},checkoutStepChangedHandler:{},clickCollectCompletedHandler:{},cookieConsentGivenHandler:{},externalLinkClickedHandler:{},helpers:{},notFoundPageViewedHandler:{},orderCompletedHandler:{},plpProductsViewedHandler:{},productAddedHandler:{},productClickedHandler:{},productDetailViewedHandler:{},productQuantityChangeHandler:{},productRemovedHandler:{},recommendationsClickedHandler:{},recommendationsViewedHandler:{},routeChangedHandler:{},siteSearchHandler:{}}},User:{userPlugin:{}}},Payment:{paymentMethod:e,termsAccepted:a},OAuth:{accessToken:e,expiry:0,timestamp:e,trackingId:e},Navigation:{hierarchy:e,path:[],loading:a,lastFetchedTopNode:l},Layout:{eyebrow:{default:e},footer:{default:e},layout:s},InfoBar:{infoBars:[],infoBarMappers:{}},Delivery:{isFetchingPickups:a,deliveries:{},pickups:{},selectedDeliveries:{}},ClickCollect:{loading:a,showDrawer:a,baseMapLocation:e,stores:[],selectedStore:e,product:e,quantity:1,form:{name:l,email:l,countryDialCode:"45",phone:l,terms:a},reservation:e,error:a,filters:{inStockOnly:t}},Checkout:{panelState:{userInfo:{},delivery:{},payment:{mustVisit:t},store:{}},desiredPanel:"auto",panelValidators:{}},Cart:{data:{id:l,lineItems:[],totalLineItemsQuantity:0,totalSalesPrice:r,totalShippingSalesPrice:r,employeeNumber:e,loyaltyNumber:e,deliveries:[],totalLineItemSalesPrice:r,totalLineItemListPrice:r,totalLineItemDiscount:r,totalShippingListPrice:r,totalShippingPriceDiscount:r,orderNumber:e,totalSalesPriceNumber:0,isActive:t,isAllLineItemsValid:t,shippingAddress:d,billingAddress:d,hash:l,discountCodes:[],source:"USER_DEVICE"},loading:{},error:e,assistedSalesMode:a,assistedSalesStoreNumber:e},Breadcrumb:{categoryTree:{},productCategory:l,lookupBreadcrumbTasks:{},currentCategoryPage:[],helpers:{}}},serverRendered:t}}(null,"",!1,!0,"0,00","default","https://sg-dam.imgix.net/services/assets.img/id/87a045c1-0923-4575-81ce-fd9b7c3bfbf6/size/original","91052931-EA","100553115",void 0)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex to validate JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583472/regex-to-validate-json)

Comment: @VishalSingh Didn't get it completely (newbie) How can I implement using python. Please show me an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a RegEx to get the Jsons from your string.

I have used this pattern: `{(?:[^{}]*{[^{]*})*[^{}]*}`

The above regex checks only the Json in one level deep.

**Code:**

```
import re
import json
input_data = """window.__NUXT__=funct ... A","100553115",void 0)"""


def json_validate(input_str):
    founds = re.findall(r"{(?:[^{}]*{[^{]*})*[^{}]*}", input_str)
    valid_jsons = []
    for x in founds:
        try:
            valid_jsons.append(json.loads(x))
        except json.JSONDecodeError:
            continue

    return valid_jsons


getting_jsons = json_validate(input_data)
for one_json in getting_jsons:
    print(one_json)
print(len(getting_jsons))
```

**It can find several (32) valid Jsons in your string:**

```
>>> python3 test.py
{'features': [{'code': 'text-TvMemory', 'label': 'Tekst TV hukommelse', 'value': '1000'}], 'label': 'Tekst TV hukommelse'}
{'features': [{'code': 'tvFeatures', 'label': 'TV funktioner', 'value': 'Netflix'}, {'code': 'tvFeatures', 'label': 'TV funktioner', 'value': 'SmartTV'}, {'code': 'tvFeatures', 'label': 'TV funktioner', 'value': 'Wi-Fi indbygget'}], 'label': 'TV funktioner'}
{'features': [{'code': 'TV.tvApps', 'label': 'TV Apps', 'value': 'Amazon'}, {'code ...
```

I have found another solution which approaches the issue from totally different way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54235803/11502612

I have tested the code from the above answer and I got the same output. It means the result is correct (probably).

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be easier to do something like

```
import json
data = json.dumps(your_string)
```

Then iterate over it to find the values. Alternatively you can look for the value locations with

```
find("{")
```

Don't know if this is what your looking for but thought it may spark an idea / alternative view