# writing json stream to file limits output size

Tags: python, json, twitter, streaming, twython

So I am writing a simple python stream listener using twython (**EDIT:** python Twitter client library), when runnining the .py the output file-size oscillates between 1 and 5kb. I would like to know what to do to make sure the file keeps getting written to. Below is the code.

```
class MyStreamer(TwythonStreamer):
def on_success(self, data):
    with open(filename,'w')as outfile:
        json.dump(data,outfile,indent=4)
        outfile.flush()
        outfile.close()

    def on_error(self, status_code, data):
    print(status_code)

stream = MyStreamer(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET,
                OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
stream.statuses.filter(track=input_string)
```

Comment: Why should the data written every time have the same size to begin with? How do you know that you are **reading** the same data every time? Have you tried adding `print(data)` or another debugging statement in the `on_success` function to check this assumption?

Comment: Are you asking how to append to a file instead of overwriting it? Use mode `a` instead of `w` when opening the file. But a sequence of JSON strings in a file is not a valid JSON file, so that's probably not a good idea.

Comment: @Dan , while streaming,  the output file size changes (ie 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1 kb etc) over a matter of seconds. Not strictly increasing in size.

Comment: @Diabellical, **why is this behavior unexpected**? If you're streaming a bunch of data from Twitter, the amount of data you get will vary unpredictably. The output file is changing in size because you are **completely overwriting it** every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not very clearly explained, but based on the comments above I think you are confused about the fact that the output file is constantly getting overwritten... rather than growing as new data is appended to it.

The problem is that your `open(filename,'w')` over-writes the file every time it goes through. Try doing this instead:

```
# global outfile 
outfile = open(filename,'w')

class MyStreamer(TwythonStreamer):
    def on_success(self, data):
        json.dump(data,outfile,indent=4)
        outfile.flush()

        def on_error(self, status_code, data):
            print(status_code)

stream = MyStreamer(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET,
                OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
stream.statuses.filter(track=input_string)

# when you are actually done writing output to it:
# outfile.close()
```

Note that this approach **will not produce a valid JSON file** because you are just concatenating together multiple chunks of JSON. But that's a separate issue. JSON isn't intended to be a "streaming" format in the first place, but [see this thread for some discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444380/is-there-a-streaming-api-for-json).