# Get value from String-Json object

Tags: java, json, performance

I have big String (which is not converted JSON):

```
{
  "MyType" : "5",
  "creationTime" : "06/03/2021 11:14:37",
  "entityCompositeKey" : "3001v4",
  ...
}
```

which another thousand lines.

I am only interested in value which is in `MyType`, I don't care about other values.

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(view);
String chiupType = jsonObj.get("MyType").toString();
```

but it's way too slow. What is the fastest way to get only one value from String(JSON)?

Comment: Possibly related: [Is there a streaming API for JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/444380)

Comment: `JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString); int value = jsonObject.getInt("MyType"); System.out.println(value);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the implementation, the whole JSON string is processed directly after the constructor has been called. Thus, there is **no** possibility to read out only a single value.

Comment: I was even thinking of taking MyType from String without even parsing because it's always comes as first value but when external app will change it - I'm done ;/

I see that  `String type = new JsonParser().parse(view).getAsJsonObject().get("MyType").getAsString();` is faster than `JSONObject`. Thanks @Sapphirex!

Comment: I would expect this argument to be accompanied with a link to the specification to proof it. Still gave an upvote since it gives a new lead to research.